# Passing a value to an interactive report region search cell

Tags: oracle-apex

I was wondering if it's possible from one page to pass an item into an IRR  search cell and then emulate the “Go” button being pressed to process that search, based on the search value item passed in?

Comment: You're not after applying a filter on one of the ir columns, but actually the row contains filter applied by using the 'Go' button?

Comment: That is correct Tom. Basically want to be able to pass a value into the IR search box and then emulate the pressing of the "Go" button. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example at https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:36

The redirect and set search button does a redirect to the same page and sets the value of a hidden item. 
(I'll use my example page as reference)

- Create a hidden item `P36_SEARCH_THIS`, value protected to No
- Create a dynamic action, fire on load, 3 true actions

  1. Execute javascript

     ```
     $("#apexir_SEARCH").val($v("P36_SEARCH_THIS"));
     gReport.search("SEARCH");
     ```
  2. Clear, item, `P36_SEARCH_THIS`
  3. Execute PLSQL Code

     ```
     apex_util.set_session_state('P36_SEARCH_THIS', NULL);
     ```
- Set the condition of the dynamic action (not the When condition) to
  `Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 is NOT NULL`, with
  `Expression 1` set to `P36_SEARCH_THIS`

Setting the item to not-protected, and the 2 dynamic actions for clearing the item aren't necessarily required, but they will prevent that the search value will be remembered, and that on a page load the search will go off again. An example would be that the search has happened, the user removes the filter,  and hits F5 at some point after that. The page will reload and filter will be reapplied.

Comment: Thanks again Tom - just have a query on the above, once I press your "Redirect and Set Search" button, which all works great, is it possible to programmatically remove the filter on "Row text contains ALLEN" as well or will your: apex_util.set_session_state('P36_SEARCH_THIS', NULL); do this? Thanks.

Comment: If what you want is a filtered report but not see the filter yet want the user to retain filter functionality: then no. You could of course alter the query where-clause to emulate the filter contains behaviour, but you'll not get close since the functionality of this filter in the IR is to only search for text in displayed columns. This might not be a huge problem too, and is entirely up to you. There is of course code that might emulate it, but is complicated. Another route would be to hide the filter box with CSS, but then all filters are hidden.

Comment: And my item blank-out prevents applying the filter in subsequent page loads. This means: the filter won't be applied after the initial redirect to the page unless you use the button again, since the dynamic action has a condition on this item's value.